# Does $\exists n \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $2^n$ can start with $9786543120$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, binomial-coefficients, exponentiation, binomial-theorem

I have tried $2^n=\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}$ but could not reach further.
Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean the leftmost or rightmost numbers in the decimal expansion are 9786543120?

Comment: Probably leftmost since he says "start with...", plus, powers of $2$ can't end in a $0$, since then it's divisible by $5$

Comment: From leftmost.- to @mathreadler

Comment: What makes you assume "starting with" is always from left? Yes exactly, that would be easier to show then.

Comment: I assume that because English, the primary language of this website, is being read from left to right. I simply generalize that to numbers being read from left to right.

Comment: Ok. Good. Then you are at least aware of your assumptions.

Comment: Why $9786543120$ and not $9876543210$ :) ? I understand that my remark has no importance !

Comment: As an aside, one can prove that there exists a power of two which starts with any desired string of digits.

Comment: There is even an OEIS entry for that: http://oeis.org/A018856

Comment: @JeanMarie : I think we all wondered that. But someone needs to say it. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes.**

We want $2^n$ to lie between $9786543120 \times 10^x$ and $9786543121 \times 10^x$. Taking logarithms, this is equivalent to finding an integer $n$ that lies between $x \frac{log 10}{\log 2} + \frac{\log 9786543120}{\log 2}$ and $x \frac{log 10}{\log 2} + \frac{\log 9786543121}{\log 2}$ for an integer $x$.

This can be achieved if we can find an $x$ such that the fractional part of $x \frac{log 10}{\log 2}$ is less than $\frac{\log 9786543121}{\log 2} - \frac{\log 9786543120}{\log 2}$. But this is always possible because $\frac{log 10}{\log 2}$ is irrational.

Comment: Dear sir, can you please elaborate the last part?

Comment: Which one, proving that $\frac{\log 10}{\log 2}$ is irrational, or proving that it  means we can find the required $x$?

Comment: The part required x.

Comment: It follows from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_approximation_theorem

Comment: But how to apply it. You see I am only a 10th grader student.

Comment: Choose N such that $1/N < \log 9786543121/\log 2−\log 9786543120/\log 2$. Then you can apply the theorem directly. Try to think about it a bit.

Comment: Why you have written about the fractional part?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**  $\log_{10} 2$ is irrational

Can you use this to prove that there exists an $m$ and $n$ such that

$$9786543120\cdot 10^n < 2^m < 9786543121 \cdot 10^n$$

> take the log base $10$ of everything.  Can you show there is some $m$ and $n$ such that $$\log_{10} 9786543120 + n < m\log_{10} 2 < \log_{10}9786543121+n$$

Comment: Dear sir, can you please alaborate?

Comment: I am only a 10th grader student.